# Should I wash the vegetables after disinfection?

Tags: food-safety, food-poisoning

Today we had an interesting question, to disinfect the fruits and vegetables we usually need to submerge them on hazardous substances like chlorine or colloidal silver (if used on increased concentrations), so maybe its a good idea to wash them again in clear wather

However wash them again will add new bacteria in to the system, beginning the process again, so is it a good idea to wash them or leave them in the disinfection liquid?

I know nothing can be 100% bacteria free, i just thought it was an interesting paradox

Comment: There are answers on cleaning of vegetables on cooking.se

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure of the quality of the water supply, it is advised to not rewash the produce, as this risks re-contaminating the produce.

With chemical disinfectants, the important bit is to get the balance of chemical to water - the dilution - correct. At a certain point, the chemical becomes harmless for human consumption.

**Source**: [Inspectapedia](https://inspectapedia.com/water/Produce_Disinfection.php)

> Watch out: If you have one of these products, read the label for the required amount of chemical to add and the wait time to use before consuming the water.

---

> Once produce has been disinfected, do not wash it again in tap water. Doing-so removes the disinfectant and in communities where tap water itself may not be sanitary you risk re-infecting the produce.